# Recieving Error when copying certain files and folders from SharePoint Windows Explorer to another SharePoint Windows Explorer

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, error, copy-and-paste

I am receiving errors on certain files and folders which I am trying to copy and paste from SharePoint 2010 to another SharePoint 2010.

Below is an example of the error:
[image]

I am receiving this for both Folders and Files.

I have full control access on both sharepoints.

Please help

Update:

So I have changed the timezone so something random. The file hasn't successfully copied over because of a new error:
[image]

Comment: what if you copy to your computer and then from there to the destination?

Comment: I can copy it to my desktop successfully but it wont copy to the SharePoint explorer @TiagoDuarte

Comment: Can you try doing the same excerise from different computer?

Comment: I'll give it ago now

Comment: Still receiving the same error @Ravindra :(

Comment: Okay in my case it was  Timezone issue. So below step i performed: i check regedit for "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\TimeZoneKeyName " key. It was empty.  Then i temporary change to different time zone from control panel and switch it back to my timezone. Everything start working. Hope this pointer helps

Comment: I don't see a HKLM in my registry @Ravindra

Comment: it means HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: Currently my TimeZoneKeyName contains "GMY Standard Time", what should I change this too? @Ravindra

Comment: To any other timezone and set it back. and try again

Comment: So its changed the error now and now im getting a
"You need permission to perform this action"

"You require permissions from the computer's administrator to make changes to this folder"

@Ravindra

Comment: You have reset the timezone back to the orignal right? and update the screen shot as well

Comment: Ive updated the image @Ravindra

Comment: You have reset the timezone back to the orignal right?

Comment: Yes I have @Ravindra

Comment: Can you do following thing , copy file from sharepoint(1) to your local computer and then copy from local computer to sharepoint(2) site

Comment: I have tried that and I receive the error which is the second screenshot @Ravindra

Comment: do you have full control on the folder on which you are copying the file? can you check that whether on the folder permission is not broken. Are you able to upload normal file on that folder?

Comment: Yes ive made sure that I do @Ravindra

Comment: can you check one last thing for me .
Open Control Panel, click Clock, Language, and Region, and then click Region and Language.
Click the Formats tab, and then click Additional settings.
what symbol you see in the Decimal symbol field?

Comment: It is a full stop @Ravindra

Comment: i am out of suggestion, hope other member will have some solution for your scenario

Answer (score 2):

To avoid these errors, I created a new SharePoint document folder, and named it something similar.

Then use the explorer view to copy over the files and folders then delete the original one and rename the new one to the same name as the original one.